# A problem related to ultrafilters on $\mathbb Z$

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, filters

I am trying to learn filters and ultrafilters.  Let $\mathcal U$ be an ultrafilter on $\mathbb Z$  . Does there exist a $f\in \ell^1(\mathbb Z)$ such that $$\lim_\mathcal U f\neq 0$$

This seems to be very basic, just can't find a way through.

I can figure out that if $\mathcal U$ happens to be the principal ultrafilter generated by integer $n$ , then we can define $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb C$ as $f(n)=1$ and $0$ elsewhere. Now for this $f$ we have $\lim_\mathcal U f=1$.

What if $\mathcal U$ is not a principal ultrafilter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the answer is no. It is easy to see that if $f\in\ell^{1}(\mathbb{Z})$, then for all $\varepsilon>0$ we have that 
$$\{n\in\mathbb{Z}:|f(n)|>\varepsilon\}$$
is a finite set. For every non-principal ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ we have that $\mathcal{U}$ contains the Fréchet filter, which is the filter containing all cofinite sets, i.e.
$$\mathcal{F}=\{X\subset\mathbb{Z}:\mathbb{Z}\setminus X\text{ is finite}\}.$$
So for all $\varepsilon>0$ we have that the set
$$Z_{\varepsilon}=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:|f(n)|<\varepsilon\}=\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{n\in\mathbb{Z}:|f(n)|>\varepsilon\}$$
is cofinite and hence $Z_{\varepsilon}\in\mathcal{U}$. Hence $\lim_{\mathcal{U}}f=0$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @LavKumar It would of course be yes for $f \in \ell^\infty(\Bbb Z)$.